# issue with wordpress plugin - simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, wordpress

```
 simplexml_load_file(http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=New%20york)
```

when i write this statement in my wordpress plugin file, It gives me this error. can any one suggest me the possible reason?

failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Comment: You're missing quotes around the URL though that should cause a different (syntax) error

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `simplexml_load_file(rawurlencode('http://example.com/?a=' . urlencode('b&c')))` unless you are in php 5.1.0 +